# how can I mock Python "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, mocking, stub, modulenotfounderror

I am testing part of the project, I have a ModuleNotFoundError as the module is in another part of the project that is not accessible, I can comment, but in the testing phase I would like to stub.

Comment: In this case you could mock the module and use it, to not receive the exception. This is the main scenario for use of mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
sys.modules['module_name'] = MagicMock()
```